# conditional binary operator expected error while runnng shell script

Tags: bash, shell

conditional binary operator expected error while running shell script.

```
 //some code
    # Parsing the input file
    while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2
    do
      key="$f1"
      case $key in
        -modules )
          module="$f2"
          ;;
        -full_run )
          fullrun="$f2"
          ;;
        -router )
          router="$f2"
          if [[ "$fullrun" == "yes" ]] && [[ $router" == "none" ]] ;
          then
            echo "If full_run is selected then router is mandatory"
            exit 1
          fi
          ;;
    //some code
```

I am getting following error while running the above script

```
./firewall_scale_estimator_configure_PRexp.sh: line 80: conditional binary operator expected
./firewall_scale_estimator_configure_PRexp.sh: line 80: syntax error near `full_run'
./firewall_scale_estimator_configure_PRexp.sh: line 80: `   echo "If full_run is selected then router is mandatory
```

Can somebody explain what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, inspect `[[ $router" == "none" ]] ;` up close. Use a syntax aware editor.

Comment: And in the general case, check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net, it'll find such errors and other pitfalls

Comment: got the issue..Thanks..simple issue but i was thinking too much